# Simple HTML sidebar example with actual conent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Every example I find is just the sidebar and the content doesn't actually change when clicking buttons in the sidebar. Is there an example where the sidebar is static but the content displayed changes?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```js
contentHTML = ["this one was hard but you managed to click it", "you clicked this first", "this one was easier to click so you clicked it second"];
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
function swap(index){
  contents.innerHTML = contentHTML[index-1];
}
```

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.sidebar{
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
}
.content{
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
}
a{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
<a onclick="swap(1)">1</a><br>
<a onclick="swap(2)">2</a><br>
<a onclick="swap(3)">3</a><br>
</div>
<div class="content">
content
</div>
```